# jQuery Tabs - multiple tab blocks on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have the following tab code:

```
<div class="block_tabs_type_1">
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1" class="current"><span>First Tab</span></a></li><!-- tab link -->
        <li><a href="#2"><span class="icon cloud"></span></a></li><!-- tab link -->
        <li><a href="#3"><span>Nested Shortcodes</span></a></li><!-- tab link -->
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab_content">
    <!-- tab content goes here -->
    <p>Duis r inceptos himenaeos.</p>
</div>

<div class="tab_content">
    <!-- tab content goes here -->
    <p>Duis tincidunt er p elit.</p>
</div>

<div class="tab_content">
    <!-- tab content goes here -->
    <p>Duis tincidunt e inceptos himenaeos.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.block_tabs_type_1 .tabs').tabs('.block_tabs_type_1 .tab_content', {
        initialIndex : 0
    });
</script>
```

I wish to add another tab block to the same page, however I am struggling to get the JS to function correctly.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply use a different selector and call it twice.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.block_tabs_type_1 .tabs').tabs('.block_tabs_type_1 .tab_content', {
        initialIndex : 0
    });
    jQuery('.block_tabs_type_2 .tabs').tabs('.block_tabs_type_2 .tab_content', {
        initialIndex : 0
    });
</script>
```